# Conditional formatting based on several columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have a table of 3 columns as follows:

```
People    test1    test2
A         90       80
B         70       60
C         50       40
D         30       50
```

I want to apply a conditional formatting rule on the table: given a person, if his score of `test2` is higher than the score of `test1`, then we make the background colour of his name `red`.

Does anyone know if we could do this in Excel? It seems to me that the conditional formatting always applies to one cell based on its own value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In Excel 2016 click the first cell you want to format, e.g. A2.
2. Click **New Rule...**
3. Click **Use a format to determine which cells to format**
4. In the field, **Format values where this formula is true**, input =C2>B2
5. Select A2 (first field with name) and click the **Format Painter** button (Home Ribbon > Clipboard > Paint Brush)
6. Click or Click and drag over the fields you want to use the same formula.

Answer (score 2):

Strategy for "conditional formatting" that is more complex than covered by the automatic ones.

If possible; select a cell and write a single formula for the evaluation. Copy the formula text into the clipboard (CTRL-C).

If the criteria is more complex, use intermediate calculations, possibly in several cells; then write a formula similar to above (in yet another cell) and copy that to the clipboard.


Select the cells that you wish to have the conditional formatting applied to.

Open the conditional formatting dialog, add a new formula based formatting and paste (CTRL-V) your formula.

Select the formatting and click OK.