# Apply conditional formatting on different column as the column with the conditional formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have an excel table that looks like this (but bigger).

[image]

If the values in the 2nd, 4th and 6th column are bigger than 0.25, I want the value in the previous column to be red with conditional formatting, like so:

[image]

I got pretty far with this question
[Conditional formatting based on several columns](https://superuser.com/questions/1275530/conditional-formatting-based-on-several-columns)
using formula =$C$4>0,25 applied to =$B$4
But this only works for one cell. How do I apply this to the entire file?

Comment: there is an applied to section on the conditional format box, you may also need to remove the $ form your formula

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the range the conditional formatting should apply to for example C1 to C3. Click conditional formatting, New Rule.
2. Enter the formule `=D1 > 0,25` or `$D1 > 0,25`.

[image]